# Ubuntu 20.04 randomly suspends

Tags: upgrade, suspend, 20.04

I've been running Ubuntu 18.10 for a while and it was all working well.  Yesterday I decided to upgrade to get onto an LTS build. I upgraded manually from 18.10 to 19.10 and then upgraded to 20.04. Now the device suspends all the time. This is a pain as I'm trying to run it as a server (as a NAS drive and Plex server). I run it headless, so I just want it to stay running 100% of the time and never suspend. This was never a problem on 18.10 but I guess something changed along the way.

I have tried modifying /etc/systemd/logind.conf to ignore all the suspend events (pasted below) but that hasn't changed anything.

Is there anything I can try to stop it from suspending?

Thanks,
Ben

```
[Login]
#NAutoVTs=6
#ReserveVT=6
#KillUserProcesses=no
#KillOnlyUsers=
#KillExcludeUsers=root
#InhibitDelayMaxSec=5
#HandlePowerKey=ignore
#HandleSuspendKey=ignore
#HandleHibernateKey=ignore
#HandleLidSwitch=ignore
#HandleLidSwitchExternalPower=ignore
#HandleLidSwitchDocked=ignore
#PowerKeyIgnoreInhibited=no
#SuspendKeyIgnoreInhibited=no
#HibernateKeyIgnoreInhibited=no
#LidSwitchIgnoreInhibited=yes
#HoldoffTimeoutSec=30s
#IdleAction=ignore
#IdleActionSec=30min
#RuntimeDirectorySize=10%
#RemoveIPC=yes
#InhibitorsMax=8192
#SessionsMax=8192
```

Comment: I just noticed that it was suggested [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1237846/ubuntu-20-04-suspends-when-idle-even-if-relevant-power-settings-are-disabled?rq=1) that using the following might work:
```sudo systemctl mask sleep.target suspend.target hibernate.target hybrid-sleep.target```

I'll try that and report back if it appears to be fixed.

Comment: if you are using it a server, a LTS release makes more sense (as normal releases require *release-upgrade* every 6-months.  Did you install a desktop release? (which will save energy) or a server release? (which assumes it's to remain on all the time?)  Also if you installed server, did you add a desktop? (thus enabling power saving functionality turning the server into a desktop, or did you mitigated these changes?)

Comment: Update: It's been over day with no suspends so the ```systemctl mask ``` command seems to have done the trick

Comment: @guiverc I did install the Desktop unfortunately. I guess that was my initial mistake. I should have just installed Server. OTOH, it was working fine that way for a long time on 18.04. I have used tasksel to install "Basic Ububtu Server" but trying to uninstall desktop or minimal desktop fails.

Comment: @guiverc I actually don't think installing the desktop vs the server version should make a "huge" difference here.  That is, yes, the two differ in terms of what packages are installed and what settings are chosen initially, but (yes, with work) one should be able to add/remove packages and settings to get what they want.  i.e., a desktop acting as a server.  Yes, 20.04 has done something that differs from all previous versions.  I've had it suspend/hibernate while I was doing some calculation and/or doing a file transfer.  The power settings in Gnome desktop had no effect...

Comment: Server setup assumes it's serving other machines, and power-saving options do not apply. Desktop configuration however assumes when the machine is idle, power-saving options are the default - ie. sleep is called for. Adding desktop software changes the configs enabling power-save... and those changes are what needs to be mitigated which I mentioned in my first comment...  @Ray  (and yeah I agree with packages issue, but packagers make assumptions that do differ between desktop packagers, and server packagers..)

Comment: @guiverc Yes, though I think there's still something "buggy" about what's happened in terms of the defaults chosen.  What you said about a desktop configuration is true but then, if I go into Settings | Power and turned off power saving, then the system should not hiberate.  In my case, I was using an Ubuntu 20.04 desktop to connect to a server via ssh to do work on the server remotely.  Clearly, I am not using the desktop "as a server" (in the traditional sense).  But, it should not go to sleep when I've switched it off in my desktop's Settings...  Yet, it did...

Answer (score 1):

I was able to resolve this using the instructions [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1237846/ubuntu-20-04-suspends-when-idle-even-if-relevant-power-settings-are-disabled?rq=1) which is using the instructions from the Ubuntu Wiki [here](https://wiki.debian.org/Suspend#Disable_suspend_and_hibernation)

Comment: Thanks for this question and the follow-up!  My search on AskUbuntu came up with your question first and not the other one...  Just wanted to nitpick your question title (for the benefit of others reading this Q&A).  I don't think the suspension is "random".  It never happens when I'm doing something -- when I'm typing either on the keyboard or remotely.  It happens when I'm away after a period of time.  Anyway, thanks!