# Why my ubuntu script is pausing if the computer is inactive?

Tags: command-line, php, laravel

I'm running a `php` script by using the `php artisan tinker` command

The script is writing an output every time an entry is saved in the DB. After 20 minutes, it stops. But as soon as I interact with the computer any how (i.e. I press a button in the keyboard), the script continues its job.

You can see the gap here:

[image]

The screen is never switching off nor is the computer snoozing.

What can I do so this does not happen and the script is continuously running until I manually stop it?

Ubuntu desktop 22.04

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu are you using? Is it a desktop or server install? Is it installed on bare metal, virtual machine, or cloud? Add these information to your question.

Comment: @user68186 it's installed in my laptop - Ubuntu 22.04

Comment: Does the computer go to sleep/suspend mode while inactive? If so [this question and answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1237846/ubuntu-20-04-suspends-when-idle-even-if-relevant-power-settings-are-disabled) may be helpful.

Comment: No, I set it up so it doesn't sleep @user68186 - when I come back after half an hour, my screen is still on and how I lef it. The only thing that seems to stop is that terminal script I'm running

Comment: I see. It may be your script specific problem then. I am not a php expert, but someone with the knowledge may help you if you post your script in your question.